# Google Analytics account transfer

Tags: google-analytics

Is there a way to transfer Google Analytics account from one account holder to another?  The original account holder was managing the site via MCC.  That person is no longer associated with the website and would like to bring analytics control inhouse. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Instructions for doing this are buried in [seemingly-unrelated documentation](http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=44500) for merging Apps accounts. Give that a shot. I'll leave the specifics over there, as it may change at some point, but the overview is:

1. Add access for a new user.
2. Make them an admin.
3. Log in as them and delete the previous admin.